# How to convert const uint8_t [] to std::string?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

The below code yields an error,

```
    void emitData(const uint8_t data[], size_t size)
    {
        std::string encodedMessage(data, size);
    }
```

Error,

```
no instance of constructor "std::__2::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>::basic_string [with _CharT=char, _Traits=std::__2::char_traits<char>, _Allocator=std::__2::allocator<char>]" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (const uint8_t *, size_t)
```

Comment: Do you want to store the integers (ie: "12345") as a string or use the `const unint8_t[]` as a raw string (as `const char[]`)?

Comment: @DhirajWishal This is a byte buffer so I need to convert to a string.

Comment: Don't edit a new question in your old question. The new question is a seperate one, with a seperate answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the overloaded constructor that takes two iterators as parameters: the beginning and ending iterator values. Simple pointers will do the trick:

```
std::string encodedMessage{data, data+size};
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried your solution on a one where string declared prior and it returns an another error. Let me edit the issue.

Comment: This is a different issue, that has nothing to do with the original question. One question per stackoverflow.com question, please. You can always post another question.

Comment: Sorry for that. I found the answer for other question. I have to use assignment operator.